# How to set data-list option value in second text box using html & JS (onChange() )

Tags: codeigniter

I have 1 datalist containing food items Name & 2nd textbox to display price of selected food item . I'm not understanding how to make a function on datalist using js to onChange display price in textbox txtprice .

```
#I'm using codeigniter  


<input list="browsers" id="browser" name="browser">
                <datalist id="browsers" onchange="getComboA(this)">
                    <?php foreach($h as $row){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row->price;?>" >                         
                            <?php echo $row->menu_name;?>
                        </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </datalist>

<div class="col-12 col-md-2"><input type="text" placeholder="Price"  class="form-control" id="txtPrice" name="txtPrice" value="<?php echo $row->price;?>" readonly >
</div>
```

eg : Item Name - Panner Tikka  | Price - 150

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy actually, you could set it up like this :

```
<input list="browsers" id="browser" name="browser" onchange="setTxtPrice(this)">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <?php foreach($h as $row){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->price;?>" >                         
            <?php echo $row->menu_name;?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</datalist>

<div class="col-12 col-md-2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Price"  class="form-control" id="txtPrice" name="txtPrice" value="<?php echo $row->price;?>" readonly >
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setTxtPrice(input1) {
    var input2 = document.getElementById('txtPrice');
    input2.value = input1.value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir , I tried your code , but I'm not getting Output as expected ..  when i select product from datalist ,its showing product price in <option> tag as well in txtprice - textbox.  [ i need option=product_name & txtPrice = product price ]   .please help

Comment: Why are you using `<datalist>` instead of `<select>`?

Comment: This code is exactly answer your question (set txtPrice when the datalist is selected), if it doesn't get output as you've expected, then you should edit your question and provide the desired behaviour you want

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to use `onchange()` in `JS`

Use `this.value` to get the value of `datalist` when option will change

```
<datalist id="browsers" onchange="PutValue(this.value)">
<?php foreach($h as $row){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row->price;?>" >                         
        <?php echo $row->menu_name;?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
```

**JS**

```
function PutValue(Value){
    $('#input_field_id').val(Value);
}
```